# Strings/signatures comparison of AntiViruses

Tags: c++, database, algorithm, antivirus, string-comparison

Does signature-based AntiVirus software match each currently-scanned file with all strings/signatures that exist in the database? Does it need to pass through all signatures in order to compare them with a file? The comparison is done from the "database to the file" not from the "file to the database", is that true ?

The second question: Is it possible to extract the string/signature (NOT Hash for whole file) by AV engine from a file first, and then see whether that string is in the database or not? Is there any known AV does this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically how this is done is that the database of known virus signatures is used to build a state machine (often something very similar to the [Aho-Corasick string search algorithm](http://www.win.tue.nl/~watson/2R080/opdracht/p333-aho-corasick.pdf)). Then, each file that is to be checked is run through the state machine. This turns out to be surprisingly fast, as all matching virus signatures can be found with a single pass through the file.